# Finding the size of a pointer without using sizeof

Tags: c++

```cpp
// Program: Reports the size of the struct 'person'.

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct person{ 
        char gender; 
        string DOB;
        float height; 
        float weight;
        
    };

    person aGuy;

    person* aGuyPtr = &aGuy;

    cout << aGuyPtr << endl;

    //Hypothetical
    cout << "Byte size: " << sizeof(aGuyPtr) << endl;
}
```

I'm trying to find the size of the pointer (in bytes). I was thinking maybe I could convert the hexadecimal into a byte?

Comment: Do you mean the "size of the object the pointer is pointing to"? The size of the pointer to a `struct` is always the same for any pointer to any given object regardless of the object's size, excepting more exotic pointers like function pointers. You can't intuit any meaning from the pointer's data itself, especially if [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is involved. You might be asking about `sizeof(*aGuyPtr)`

Comment: Tip: `using namespace std;` is a bad habit to get into and if you can stop now you might avoid a whole lot of headaches in the future. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason: It avoids conflict with your own classes, structures and variables especially when you’re importing a lot of header files which may define a lot more things than they superficially appear to.

Comment: @tadman not really. Pointers-to-members do not have to have the same sizes as regular pointers (and indeed, pointers to virtual functions are usually twice the size of the regular pointer)

Comment: @SergeyA Well, I'd suggest those aren't normal pointers, but function pointers, which are a whole different deal.

Comment: @tadman - There is no such guarantee in pure standard C or C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Added some clarification there. I mean in the case of `&x` for a given type `class x` or `struct x` where the size of the class/struct does not impact the size of the pointer.

Comment: `sizeof` is how you get the size of something in bytes. If you're not going to use the tool that's made for that job, you need to explain why so people can properly find something else.

Comment: I agree with the others. This is a very strange question. "Here is a perfect, simple, built-in way to solve the problem I have. Is there some other way to do it?" Why? What's wrong with `sizeof`? Without knowing why you don't want to use it, it's vey hard to suggest something you'll like more. There are some awful hacks you can do, such as looking at array offsets, but *why*?!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find the size of the pointer (in bytes).

This is what `sizeof` does. This is the purpose of `sizeof`. `sizeof` is the best tool to achieve this. If you want to know the size of a type, you should be using `sizeof`.

Your hypothetical example works correctly.

> Finding the size of a pointer without using sizeof

There is no reason to do this without `sizeof`.

That said, if you have a pointer/reference to the object, then you can technically find the size by incrementing pointer to such object, then reinterpret the original and incremented pointer as pointer to char, and subtracting the reinterpreted original from the reinterpreted incremented pointer. Don't do this.

Answer (score -2):

Nothing that a little-bit of pointer arithmetic cannot solve.

```
#include <iostream>

using T = int;
template<typename T>
std::size_t get_size(){
    T* ptr = 0;
    ++ptr;// Will increment in sizeof(T)
    return ptrdiff_t((char*)ptr - 0); // Size in bytes
}
int main(){
    std::cout<<"Pointer size: "<<get_size<void*>()<<'\n';//Since all pointers have the same size, the type is irrelevant
    std::cout<<"Int size: "<<get_size<int>()<<'\n';
}
```

The possible result on Godbolt's machine:

```
Pointer size: 8
Int size: 4
```

Comment: The `get_size()` function shown is no different then just using `sizeof()` instead of pointer arithmetic: `template<typename T> std::size_t get_size() { return sizeof(T); }` So just use `sizeof()` directly instead: `std::cout << "Pointer size: " << sizeof(void*) << '\n'; std::cout << "Int size: " << sizeof(int) << '\n';`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I completely agree, but the question states "Finding the size of a pointer **without using sizeof**".

Comment: Except maybe as a learning experience in pointer arithmetic, there is no good reason not to use `sizeof()` otherwise, since it is built in to the language itself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Again, I fully agree with you :] I am simply answering the question as it currently is stated. There is a good chance the author did not know actually what they want, they can edit their question and I can change/delete my answer.